# Selenium C# Extent Report using multiple Classes

Tags: c#, selenium, extentreports

I am creating selenium C# frameworke and added Extent Report in it. I have two classes when I run my code my first-class test report gets overwritten by the second class Test report. How can I generate multiple class extent reports in a single report. I know my test variable of ExtentTest is getting over-written when a new class gets execute but I do not know how to fix it. I know in Java we can use ITestReport but in C# no function like that is working.

**My Base Class:**

````
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;
        public static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentTest test ;
        public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;


        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void ExtendStart()
        {
        
                extent = new ExtentReports();
                 htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\TitleHoundEndToEndTesting\\TitleHoundEndToEndTesting\\ExtentReports\\Current-SeleniumRepprt.html");
                extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

        }
        [SetUp]
        public void startBrowser()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        }
        public MediaEntityModelProvider CaptureScreenShot()
        {
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsBase64EncodedString;
            return MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(screenshot).Build();

        }
    
        [TearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
           
            driver.Close();
        }```


**My Login Class**

  ```      [Test]
        public void BLoginTest()
        {
            try
            {
                test = extent.CreateTest("Login Test Is Getting Exectuted");
                driver.Url = "https://test.line.com/";
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                var login = new Login(driver);
                login.LoginMethod();
                test.Log(Status.Pass, "Login Test Method is Passed");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (attempts <= 3)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Thread.Sleep(8000);
                    BLoginTest();
                }
                else
                {
                    var ss = CaptureScreenShot();
                    test.Log(Status.Fail, "Login Test Method is Failed" + e, ss);
                    Assert.Fail();
                }
            }
        }```

**My NewQuote Class**

```  [Test]
        public void ANewQuoteTest()
        {
            try
            {
                test = extent.CreateTest("NewQuote Test Is Getting Exectuted");
                driver.Url = "https://test.titlehoundonline.com/";
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                var newqoute = new NewQuote(driver);
                newqoute.GetQouteMethod();
                test.Log(Status.Pass, "Login Test Method is Passed");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                if (attempts <= 3)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Thread.Sleep(8000);
                    ANewQuoteTest();
                }
                else
                {
                    var ss = CaptureScreenShot();
                    test.Log(Status.Fail, "LogOutTest Test Method is Failed" + e, ss);
                    Assert.Fail();
                }
            }
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't see EndTest, Flush, Close mehod call for extent object. Report are written only when you call flush. To add all test case result in report, use proper method(eg. Aftermethod/after class) to write on extent report.And use flush/ close in teardown,Aftersuite.

Comment: ` [TearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
           
            driver.Close();
        }
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void ExtentReprot()
        {
            extent.Flush();
        }`

Comment: I am using but still, every class report is getting overwritten